# How to implement custom evaluation jobs (with custom metrics for custom learning tasks) in Vertex AI

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-vertex-ai, gcp-ai-platform-training, vertex-ai-pipeline

From what I can see in GCP's official docs:
https://cloud.google.com/vertex-ai/docs/evaluation/introduction

Evaluation job comes with predefined metrics for predefined tasks. If I have a training task that's slightly more bespoke with metrics/ objective outside the scope of the available tasks/ metrics, how would I implement them?

Examples of custom metrics are MMD or KL Divergence loss etc.

My current thinking is:

1. Create a custom evaluation app in a docker container
2. Create a CustomJob that runs my evaluation app
3. Output the evaluation artefacts (e.g. results, plots) to GCS etc?

Many thanks in advance!